# (EventLogAppender) Can we set the event category at runtime, without recreating the appender?

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

This is a base class, so I'm configuring an EventLogAppender entirely at runtime, like so:

```
Public MustInherit Class EventLogger
  Public Sub Test(EventSource As String)
    Dim oAppender As IAppender

    oAppender = New EventLogAppender

    With DirectCast(oAppender, EventLogAppender)
      .ApplicationName = EventSource
      .Category = 0 ' <========== Would like to set this value when logging 
      .EventId = 0
      .Layout = New PatternLayout("%level: {0} %message%newline".ToFormat(EventSource))
      .ActivateOptions()
    End With

    BasicConfigurator.Configure(oAppender)
    Me.Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Me.GetType)
    Me.Logger.Info("Test")
  End Sub

  Private Logger As ILog
End Class

Public Module Extensions
  <Extension>
  Public Function ToFormat(Template As String, ParamArray Values As Object()) As String
    Return String.Format(Template, Values)
  End Function
End Module
```

It's easy enough to set the event category while building up the appender, but I'd like the category to correspond with the log level.

Is there a way to do this without having to build a special appender for each log level at the time the logger is called? That's sure to be a performance killer.

It doesn't look like it, but I could be wrong. It happened to me once before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it. Thanks to [Stafford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32173607/722393) for providing the solution... add an `IAppender` for each Category and set its filter accordingly. Performance isn't impacted because this only happens once.

Here's how:

```
Public Class EvAppender
  Inherits EventLogAppender

  Private Sub New(ApplicationName As String, Category As Categories)
    Me.ApplicationName = ApplicationName
    Me.Category = Category
    Me.EventId = 0
    Me.Layout = New PatternLayout("Level: %level%newlineSource: %logger.%M()%newlineMessage: %message%newline%exception")
    Me.Name = "{0}Appender".ToFormat(Category.ToString)

    Me.AddMapping(Me.GetMapping(Level.Debug))
    Me.AddMapping(Me.GetMapping(Level.Info))
    Me.AddMapping(Me.GetMapping(Level.Warn))
    Me.AddMapping(Me.GetMapping(Level.Error))
    Me.AddMapping(Me.GetMapping(Level.Fatal))

    Me.AddFilter(New LevelRangeFilter With
                 {
                  .LevelMin = Me.LogLevel(Category),
                  .LevelMax = Me.LogLevel(Category)
                 })

    Me.ActivateOptions()
  End Sub



  Public Shared Function Build(ApplicationName As String) As List(Of EvAppender)
    Build = New List(Of EvAppender)
    Build.Add(New EvAppender(ApplicationName, Categories.Debug))
    Build.Add(New EvAppender(ApplicationName, Categories.Info))
    Build.Add(New EvAppender(ApplicationName, Categories.Warn))
    Build.Add(New EvAppender(ApplicationName, Categories.Error))
    Build.Add(New EvAppender(ApplicationName, Categories.Fatal))
  End Function



  Private Function GetMapping(LogLevel As Level) As EventLogAppender.Level2EventLogEntryType
    GetMapping = New EventLogAppender.Level2EventLogEntryType
    GetMapping.Level = LogLevel

    Select Case GetMapping.Level
      Case Level.Debug : GetMapping.EventLogEntryType = EventLogEntryType.Information
      Case Level.Info : GetMapping.EventLogEntryType = EventLogEntryType.Information
      Case Level.Warn : GetMapping.EventLogEntryType = EventLogEntryType.Warning
      Case Level.Error : GetMapping.EventLogEntryType = EventLogEntryType.Error
      Case Level.Fatal : GetMapping.EventLogEntryType = EventLogEntryType.Error
    End Select
  End Function



  Private Function GetLogLevel(Category As Categories) As Level
    Select Case Category
      Case Categories.Debug : LogLevel = Level.Debug
      Case Categories.Info : LogLevel = Level.Info
      Case Categories.Warn : LogLevel = Level.Warn
      Case Categories.Error : LogLevel = Level.Error
      Case Categories.Fatal : LogLevel = Level.Fatal
      Case Else : LogLevel = Level.All
    End Select
  End Function



  Private Enum Categories
    Debug = 3
    Info = 4
    Warn = 6
    [Error] = 7
    Fatal = 11
  End Enum
End Class
```

Use it like this:

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure(EvAppender.Build(ApplicationName).ToArray)
Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(ApplicationName)
```